# Checking for Referential Integrity Violation before deletion in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an object `Tag` that is linked to a whole bunch of other objects.  I am attempting to handle the *Delete* for this object.  I simply don't want to delete the tag if it is associated to any other objects.

At the moment I am solving it like this:

```
if(tag.Stands.Count == 0 && tag.Skids.Count == 0
   && tag.Panels.Count == 0 && tag.Devices.Count == 0
   && tag.Cables.Count == 0 && tag.JunctionBoxes.Count == 0)
{
    _db.Tags.DeleteObject(tag);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I don't check for all these things, I obviously get a reference constraint error, e.g.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted
>   with the REFERENCE constraint "FKStandTag237968".

I know a way to get around this is with cascading deletes but it is actual business logic that tags shouldn't be deleted if they are associated to any other object.

Is there a way using the Entity Framework that I can check that I won't break any constraints on the DB before attempting to save a delete?  Something along the lines of `_db.IsValidToDelete(object)`?

Comment: That is an error you need to handle at the database level, so you must create a new Context to deal with it.

Comment: I suggest looking at UnitOfWork and looking here http://lavinski.tumblr.com/post/9114111237/object-relational-mapper-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having such a method (`_db.IsValidToDelete(object)`) will not guarantee you that it is safe to delete. Your application is a multi-user application. So one user may associate a tag when another user tries to delete it.

So better alternative would be to allow user to delete the tag and catch the exception to examine whether it is a referential integrity violation.

Comment: I see your point.  However the exception that is thrown is an `UpdateException` containing an `SqlException`.  I'm worried if I catch a broad exception like either of those I might be covering up other bugs.  Is that a valid worry?

Comment: @link664 catching and swallowing exceptions are two different things. You examine the exception to see if you can handle it otherwise throw it.

Answer (score 2):

Btw. each call like `tag.Stands.Count` will load all related `Stands` from the database to your application so if you have a lot of relations and each contain a lot of entities this validation will be damn expensive and slow.

You can either use @Eranga's advice and catch exception or create stored procedure for tag deletion.